# target .each from dynamic dom

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamic DOM elements i would like to target using `.each` 
when i the elements are loaded with a delay, `.each` does'nt seem to pick this up. 
How can i make this work?

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('body').append('<div id="nav">'+
        '<ul>'+
            '<li><a>button 1</a></li>'+
            '<li><a>button 2</a></li>'+
            '<li><a>button 3</a></li>'+
        '</ul>'+
    '</div>');
}, 1000);

$("#nav ul li").each(function (index) {
    $(this).delegate('a', 'click', function(){
        alert(index); //NOTHING HAPPENS
        return false;
    });
});
```

thank you Sushanth
heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/rN9tJ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like `the #nav is not a static parent` as It  was still not inserted into the DOM when the click event is being associated .

So `attach it to a higher static parent` .

Also You don't need a Loop in the first place..

**Delegate the event** to the `body`

```
$('body').delegate('#nav ul li a', 'click', function(){
        alert(index); 
        return false;
 });
```

Also .delegate() is deprecated in the latest version ..
Use .on() instead..

```
$('body').on('click', '#nav ul li a', function(){
       alert(index); 
       return false;
 });
```

Comment: thank you,  would `delegate` to `body` be good practice in general?  my example was just for demonstration but in real world the dynamic dom might come from a button click rather than delay.

Comment: I am delegating to the body because I do not know the HTML structure in this case .. The closer the static parent the better ... So if you have a container closer than the body then it is better to attach to that element

Comment: i see,  also from your example you said not to loop but then how do i get the index?

Comment: you can just do $(this).index()

Comment: can you set up a fiddle for this

Comment: oops.. You need to do alert ( $('a').index(this) )